# Regular expression alteration not matching in BASH

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I have been trying to get multiple not matching alteration to work in a BASH.

This is what I am trying to not match. If there are two parameters and a switch(-a,-b,-c,-d) is the first parameter.

Example:
./scriptname -a filename
./scriptname -d filename

What I want this to echo success is for:
./scriptname filename ipaddress.

The code that  works is :

```
if [[ "$#" = "2" && "$1" =~ ([^-a][^-b][^-c]) ]]
    then
        echo "success"
    else
        echo "fail"
  fi
```

If I try to expand on the alteration with `([^-a][^-b][^-c][^-d])` it stops working. I have tried multiple syntax variants and nothing seems to work. I also tried to group them together like:

`if [[ "$#" = "2" && "$1" =~ ([^-a][^-b]) && "$1" =~ ([^-c][^-d]) ]]` and this fails as well.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `[^-a][^-b]` matches two characters, the first of which cannot be dash or a, and the second cannot be dash or b. Do you mean `-[^abcd]` i. e. dash followed by a character other than a, b, c, or d?

Comment: I have switches within the script. I am trying to read positional parameters and ensure the switch is not being used for 2 parameters.

Comment: Please edit the question with examples of inputs which should and should not be matched.

Comment: Why not use `getopts` to handle the options, then check what is leftover?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
if [[ "$#" = "2" && "$1" =~ -[a-d]$ ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I honestly forgotten all about that command. This should work. Thanks.